# Filter base on multiple conditions and variables

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm working with survey data and I need to filter by a bunch of multiple response variables, 543 variables to be precise.

Being my data like this:

```r
Q1 <- c(1,0,1,1)
Q2 <- c(0,1,0,0)
Q3 <- c(1,1,1,0)
Q4 <- c(0,0,0,0)
Q5 <- c(1,0,0,0)
DT <- data.frame(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
```

I want to know how many people response at least one of this questions, so the code using dplyr package should be:

```r
MR <- DT %>%
   filter(Q1 == 1 | Q2 == 1 | Q3 == 1 | Q4 == 1 | Q5 == 1 )

nrow(MR)
```

Basically, I'm trying to avoid write an extensive code from variable 1 until variable 543; like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
MR <- DT %>%
   filter(Q1 == 1 | Q2 == 1 | Q3 == 1 | Q4 == 1 | Q5 == 1 | ... | Q543 == 1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to filter by so many variables?

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "how many people response at least one of this questions"   given that these are multiple responses do you mean that they gave exactly one response ( that the sum of the responses is 1) or that they gave at least one response (that the sum of the responses is >= 1)

Comment: Also please show the expected result for this sample data.

Comment: Also would it make sense to ad a 5th element to each vector that is 0 for all of them? Otherwise how do you know if the code works.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, with `a,b,c,d,e` I meant Q1,...,Q5. I already change it

Comment: @Elin the data came from a survey where the people associate certain characteristics to several companies. The surveyed only responded to those companies they knew (measured with a previous question), so there are rows with only zeros

Comment: But in your sample data you have no such rows, so you should add one row like that and also provide an example of what you want the results from that data to look like. That is what people mean by a minimal complete verifiable example.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do this.  One option is `filter_at` where we specify the variables to be selected with one of the `select_helpers` (`matches` - the column names that start (`^`) with "Q" followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string, and with `any_vars`, create the logic. It keeps the rows that have at least one value in a column equal to 1

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
   filter_at(vars(matches("^Q\\d+$")), any_vars(.==1))
```

---

Or using `map` and `reduce`.  We loop through the `select`ed columns with `map`, create a logical `vector` and `reduce` it to a single logical `vector` with `|`.  This can be used in `filter` to filter the rows

```
library(purrr)
DT %>%
   filter(map(select(., matches("^Q\\d+$")), `==`, 1) %>% 
             reduce(`|`))
```

---

Or another way is `rowSums`

```
DT %>%
   filter(rowSums(select(., matches("^Q\\d+$")) ==1) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R one liner:

```
DT[c(sort(unique(unlist(lapply(DT, function(x){which(x==1)}))))),]
```